# Need a tool to compare the contents of two directories

Tags: command-line, files, folder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File and directory comparison tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12473/file-and-directory-comparison-tool)

I'm looking for a tool(or anything that do the job )  that compare the contains of two folder and show the differences between them.  I want the file list and if possible the different contents between files with same path.

Does anyone now the simpliest way to do that ?