# Is there any command line interactive tool like meld?

Tags: command-line, vim, git, text-editor, diff

I usually work on someone else's code base on a remote system and often need to merge code from two different files. For that I have to pull files to my system and meld it and push it back to the remote system. Is there any better way to do it through the terminal itself? (i.e. Terminal and command-line equivalent of [Meld Diff Viewer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/meld/))?

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/12473/file-and-directory-comparison-tool

Comment: Sounds like you want a [revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_control) (which are usually built on top of `diff`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about Vimdiff?

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/vimdiff-file-diff-tool/

It might not look as fancy as Meld, but it looks like a great option for visual diffing in terminal.

Comment: So much better than meld, no GTK lib issues!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the perfect use for a distributed version control system like either [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

A very good tutorial for Mercurial is available [here](http://hginit.com):

http://hginit.com

Comment: … or any revision control system for that matter.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But i am already using git and wanted to merge two files with same name. I think vimdiff what i needed as @Tobberoth suggested.