# How to compare two files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to compare two files line by line and by column number 2. How could I accomplish this?

File_1.txt:

```
User1 US
User2 US
User3 US
```

File_2.txt:

```
User1 US
User2 US
User3 NG
```

Output_File:

```
User3 has changed
```

Comment: Use `diff "File_1.txt" "File_2.txt"`

Comment: Also visit : http://askubuntu.com/q/12473/

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Look into the `diff` command. It's a good tool, and you can read all about it by typing  `man diff` into your terminal.

The command you'll want to do is `diff File_1.txt File_2.txt` which will output the difference between the two and should look something like this:

[image]

A quick note on reading the output from the third command: The 'arrows' (`<` and `>`) refer to what the value of the line is in the left file (`<`) vs the right file (`>`), with the left file being the one you entered first on the command line, in this case `File_1.txt`

Additionally you might notice the 4th command is `diff ... | tee Output_File` this pipes the results from `diff` into a `tee`, which then puts that output into a file, so that you can save it for later if you don't want to view it all on the console right that second.

Comment: Can this do other files (such as images)? Or is it limited to just documents?

Comment: As far as I know, it's limited to text files. Code will work, as it's essentially text, but any binary files (which pictures are) will just get junk out. You CAN compare to see if they're identical by doing: `diff file1 file2 -s`. Here's an example: http://imgur.com/ShrQx9x

Comment: Is there a way to colorize the output? I'd like keeping it CLI-only, but with some more... human touch.

Comment: Instead of tee you can just redirect the output: "diff file1.txt file2.txt > ouput.txt"?

Answer (score 52):

Or you can use [Meld Diff](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/meld/)

> Meld helps you compare files, directories, and version controlled
>   projects. It provides two- and three-way comparison of both files and
>   directories, and has support for many popular version control systems.

Install by running:

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

Your example:

[image]

Compare directory:

[image]

Example with full of text:

[image]

Answer (score 35):

You can use [vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html).

Example:

```
vimdiff  file1  file2
```

Comment: this one has colors

Comment: This helped me as it showed my first file's line ending was in `dos` and second one in `unix`.

Answer (score 27):

FWIW, I rather like what I get with side-by-side output from diff

```
diff -y -W 120 File_1.txt File_2.txt
```

would give something like:

```
User1 US                            User1 US
User2 US                            User2 US
User3 US                          | User3 NG
```

Comment: Another useful option is `--suppress-common-lines` to show only changes

Answer (score 12):

You can use the command [`cmp`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cmp):

```
cmp -b "File_1.txt" "File_2.txt"
```

output would be

```
a b differ: byte 25, line 3 is 125 U 116 N
```

Comment: `cmp` is much faster than `diff` if all you want is the return code.

Answer (score 8):

`Meld` is a really great tool. But you can also use `diffuse` to visually compare two files:

```
diffuse file1.txt file2.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Litteraly sticking to the question (file1, file2, outputfile with "has changed" message)  the script below works.

Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `compare.py`, make it executable, run it by the command:

```
/path/to/compare.py <file1> <file2> <outputfile>
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
file1 = sys.argv[1]; file2 = sys.argv[2]; outfile = sys.argv[3]

def readfile(file):
    with open(file) as compare:
        return [item.replace("\n", "").split(" ") for item in compare.readlines()]

data1 = readfile(file1); data2 = readfile(file2)
mismatch = [item[0] for item in data1 if not item in data2]

with open(outfile, "wt") as out:
    for line in mismatch:
        out.write(line+" has changed"+"\n")
```

With a few extra lines, you can make it either print to an outputfile, or to the terminal, depending on if the outputfile is defined:

To print to a file:

```
/path/to/compare.py <file1> <file2> <outputfile>
```

To print to the terminal window:

```
/path/to/compare.py <file1> <file2>
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

file1 = sys.argv[1]; file2 = sys.argv[2]
try:
    outfile = sys.argv[3]
except IndexError:
    outfile = None

def readfile(file):
    with open(file) as compare:
        return [item.replace("\n", "").split(" ") for item in compare.readlines()]

data1 = readfile(file1); data2 = readfile(file2)
mismatch = [item[0] for item in data1 if not item in data2]

if outfile != None:
        with open(outfile, "wt") as out:
            for line in mismatch:
                out.write(line+" has changed"+"\n")
else:
    for line in mismatch:
        print line+" has changed"
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to use `colordiff`, which behaves like `diff` but colorizes its output. This is very helpful for reading diffs. Using your example,

```
$ colordiff -u File_1.txt File_2.txt
--- File_1.txt  2016-12-24 17:59:17.409490554 -0500
+++ File_2.txt  2016-12-24 18:00:06.666719659 -0500
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 User1 US
 User2 US
-User3 US
+User3 NG
```

where the `u` option gives a unified diff. This is how the colorized diff looks like:

[image]

Install `colordiff` by running `sudo apt-get install colordiff`.

Comment: If you want colors I find the diff built into vim to actually be easy to use, as in the answer by Mr.S

Answer (score 3):

Install **git** and use

```
$ git diff filename1 filename2
```

And you will get output in nice colored format

**Git** installation

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install git-core
```

Answer (score 3):

## colcmp.sh

Compares name/value pairs in 2 files in the format `name value\n`.  Writes the `name` to `Output_file` if changed.  Requires bash v4+ for [associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047648/bash-4-associative-arrays-error-declare-a-invalid-option).

### Usage

```
$ ./colcmp.sh File_1.txt File_2.txt
User3 changed from 'US' to 'NG'
no change: User1,User2
```

### Output_File

```
$ cat Output_File
User3 has changed
```

### Source (colcmp.sh)

```
cmp -s "$1" "$2"
case "$?" in
    0)
        echo "" > Output_File
        echo "files are identical"
        ;;
    1)
        echo "" > Output_File
        cp "$1" ~/.colcmp.array1.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/([^A-Za-z0-9 ])/\\\\\\1/g" ~/.colcmp.array1.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/^(.*)$/#\\1/" ~/.colcmp.array1.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/^#\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S.*?)\\s*\$/A1\\[\\1\\]=\"\\2\"/" ~/.colcmp.array1.tmp.sh
        chmod 755 ~/.colcmp.array1.tmp.sh
        declare -A A1
        source ~/.colcmp.array1.tmp.sh

        cp "$2" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/([^A-Za-z0-9 ])/\\\\\\1/g" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/^(.*)$/#\\1/" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/^#\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S.*?)\\s*\$/A2\\[\\1\\]=\"\\2\"/" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        chmod 755 ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        declare -A A2
        source ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh

        USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE=
        for i in "${!A1[@]}"; do
            if [ "${A2[$i]+x}" = "" ]; then
                echo "$i was removed"
                echo "$i has changed" > Output_File
            fi
        done
        for i in "${!A2[@]}"; do
            if [ "${A1[$i]+x}" = "" ]; then
                echo "$i was added as '${A2[$i]}'"
                echo "$i has changed" > Output_File
            elif [ "${A1[$i]}" != "${A2[$i]}" ]; then
                echo "$i changed from '${A1[$i]}' to '${A2[$i]}'"
                echo "$i has changed" > Output_File
            else
                if [ x$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE != x ]; then
                    USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE=",$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE"
                fi
                USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE="$i$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE"
            fi
        done
        if [ x$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE != x ]; then
            echo "no change: $USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE"
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "error: file not found, access denied, etc..."
        echo "usage: ./colcmp.sh File_1.txt File_2.txt"
        ;;
esac
```

---

## Explanation

Breakdown of the code and what it means, to the best of my understanding.  I welcome edits and suggestions.

### Basic File Compare

```
cmp -s "$1" "$2"
case "$?" in
    0)
        # match
        ;;
    1)
        # compare
        ;;
    *)
        # error
        ;;
esac
```

[**cmp**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp) will set the value of [**$?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-in-shell-scripts) as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmp_(Unix)#Return_values):

- 0 = files match
- 1 = files differ
- 2 = error

I chose to use a [**case**..**esac**](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) statement to evalute **$?** because [the value of **$?** changes after every command, including **test**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19441/how-to-use-and-test-to-check-function) ([).

Alternatively I could have used a variable to hold the value of [**$?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-in-shell-scripts):

```
cmp -s "$1" "$2"
CMPRESULT=$?
if [ $CMPRESULT -eq 0 ]; then
    # match
elif [ $CMPRESULT -eq 1 ]; then
    # compare
else
    # error
fi
```

Above does the same thing as the case statement.  IDK which I like better.

## Clear the Output

```
        echo "" > Output_File
```

Above clears the output file so if no users changed, the output file will be empty.

I do this inside the **case** statements so that the **Output_file** remains unchanged on error.

### Copy User File to Shell Script

```
        cp "$1" ~/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh
```

Above copies **File_1.txt** to the current user's home dir.

For example, if the current user is john, the above would be the same as **cp "File_1.txt" /home/john/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh**

### Escape Special Characters

Basically, I'm paranoid.  I know that these characters could have special meaning or execute an external program when run in a script as part of variable assignment:

- ` - back-tick - executes a program and the output as if the output were part of your script
- $ - dollar sign - usually prefixes a variable
- ${} - allows for more complex variable substitution
- $() - idk what this does but i think it can execute code

What I *don't know* is how much I don't know about bash.  I don't know what other characters might have special meaning, but I want to escape them all with a backslash:

```
        sed -i -E "s/([^A-Za-z0-9 ])/\\\\\\1/g" ~/.colcmp.array1.tmp.sh
```

[**sed**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-complex-string-preferrably-with-regex) can do a lot more than [regular expression pattern matching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-complex-string-preferrably-with-regex).  The script pattern **"s/(find)/(replace)/"** specifically performs the pattern match.

**"s/(find)/(replace)/(modifiers)"**

- (find) = ([^A-Za-z0-9 ])

  - () = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 1
  - [] = match a character from a [specific list of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex)
  - [^] = match any character [NOT in a specific list of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944357/carets-in-regular-expressions)
  - [^A-Za-z0-9 ] = match any character that is NOT a letter, digit or space

**in english:** capture any punctuation or special character as caputure group 1 (\\1)

- (replace) = \\\\\\1

  - \\\\ = literal character (\\) i.e. a backslash
  - \\1 = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 1

**in english:** prefix all special characters with a backslash

- (modifiers) = g

  - g = globally replace

**in english:** if more than one match is found on the same line, replace them all

### Comment Out the Entire Script

```
        sed -i -E "s/^(.*)$/#\\1/" ~/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh
```

Above uses a regular expression to prefix every line of **~/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh** with a bash comment character (**#**).  I do this because later I intend to execute **~/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh** using the **source** command and because I don't know for sure the whole format of **File_1.txt**.

I don't want to accidentally execute arbitrary code.  I don't think anyone does.

**"s/(find)/(replace)/"**

- (find) = ^(.*)$

  - ^ = [beginning of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)
  - () = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 1
  - .* = [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666768/how-dot-star-works)
  - \$ = [end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)

**in english:** capture each line as caputure group 1 (\\1)

- (replace) = #\\1

  - # = literal character (#) i.e. a pound symbol or hash
  - \\1 = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 1

**in english:** replace each line with a pound symbol followed by the line that was replaced

### Convert User Value to A1[User]="value"

```
        sed -i -E "s/^#\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S.*?)\\s*\$/A1\\[\\1\\]=\"\\2\"/" ~/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh
```

**Above is the core of this script.**

- convert this: `#User1 US`

  - to this: `A1[User1]="US"`
  - or this: `A2[User1]="US"` (for the 2nd file)

**"s/(find)/(replace)/"**

- (find) = ^#\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S.*?)\\s*\$

  - ^ = [beginning of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)
  - # = literal character (#) i.e. a pound symbol or hash
  - \\s* - zero or more [whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750716/what-does-regular-expression-s-s-do)
  - () = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 1
  - \\S+ - one or more [NON-whitespace characters](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/invert-regular-expression-matches-with-javascript-s-vs-s/187456)
  - \\s+ - one or more [whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750716/what-does-regular-expression-s-s-do)
  - () = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 2
  - \\S - exactly one [NON-whitespace character](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/invert-regular-expression-matches-with-javascript-s-vs-s/187456)
  - .*? = [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666768/how-dot-star-works), [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy)
  - \\s* - zero or more [whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750716/what-does-regular-expression-s-s-do)
  - \$ = [end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)

in english:

- require but ignore leading comment characters (#)
- ignore leading whitespace
- capture the first word as caputure group 1 (\\1)
- require a space (or tab, or whitespace)

  - that will be replaced with an equals sign because
  - it's not part of any capture group, and because
  - the (replace) pattern puts an equals sign between capture group 1 and capture group 2
- capture the rest of the line as capture group 2
- (replace) = A1\\[\\1\\]=\"\\2\"

  - A1\\[ - literal characters `A1[` to start array assignment in an array called `A1`
  - \\1 = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 1 - which does not include the leading hash (#) and does not include leading whitespace - in this case capture group 1 is being used to set the name of the name/value pair in the bash associative array.
  - \\]=\" = literal characters `]="`

    - `]` = close array assignment e.g. `A1[`User1`]="`US`"`
    - `=` = assignment operator e.g. variable=value
    - `"` = quote value to capture spaces ... although now that i think about it, it would have been easier to let the code above that backslashes everything to also backslash space characters.
  - \\1 = [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) 2 - in this case, the value of the name/value pair
  - " = closing quote value to capture spaces

**in english:** replace each line in the format `#name value` with an array assignment operator in the format `A1[name]="value"`

### Make Executable

```
        chmod 755 ~/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh
```

Above uses [chmod](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) to make the array script file executable.

I'm not sure if this is necessary.

### Declare Associative Array (bash v4+)

```
        declare -A A1
```

The capital -A indicates that the variables declared will be [associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047648/bash-4-associative-arrays-error-declare-a-invalid-option).

This is why the script requires bash v4 or greater.

### Execute our Array Variable Assignment Script

```
        source ~/.colcmp.arrays.tmp.sh
```

We have already:

- converted our file from lines of `User value` to lines of `A1[User]="value"`,
- made it executable (maybe), and
- declared A1 as an associative array...

Above we [**source**](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) the script to run it in the current shell.  We do this so we can keep the variable values that get set by the script.  If you execute the script directly, it spawns a new shell, and the variable values are lost when the new shell exits, or at least that's my understanding.

### This Should Be a Function

```
        cp "$2" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/([^A-Za-z0-9 ])/\\\\\\1/g" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/^(.*)$/#\\1/" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        sed -i -E "s/^#\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S.*?)\\s*\$/A2\\[\\1\\]=\"\\2\"/" ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        chmod 755 ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
        declare -A A2
        source ~/.colcmp.array2.tmp.sh
```

We do the same thing for **$1** and **A1** that we do for **$2** and **A2**.  It really should be a function.  I think at this point this script is confusing enough and it works, so I'm not gonna fix it.

### Detect Users Removed

```
        for i in "${!A1[@]}"; do
            # check for users removed
        done
```

Above loops through [associative array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-arrays-in-bash)

```
            if [ "${A2[$i]+x}" = "" ]; then
```

Above uses variable substitution to detect the difference between a value that is unset vs a variable that has been explicitly set to a zero length string.

Apparently, there are a lot of ways to [see if a variable has been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash).  I chose the one with the most votes.

```
                echo "$i has changed" > Output_File
```

Above adds the user **$i** to the **Output_File**

### Detect Users Added or Changed

```
        USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE=
```

Above clears a variable so we can keep track of users that did not change.

```
        for i in "${!A2[@]}"; do
            # detect users added, changed and not changed
        done
```

Above loops through [associative array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-arrays-in-bash)

```
            if ! [ "${A1[$i]+x}" != "" ]; then
```

Above uses variable substitution to [see if a variable has been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash).

```
                echo "$i was added as '${A2[$i]}'"
```

Because **$i** is the array key (user name) $A2[$i] should return the value associated with the current user from **File_2.txt**.

For example, if **$i** is **User1**, the above reads as **${A2[User1]}**

```
                echo "$i has changed" > Output_File
```

Above adds the user **$i** to the **Output_File**

```
            elif [ "${A1[$i]}" != "${A2[$i]}" ]; then
```

Because **$i** is the array key (user name) $A1[$i] should return the value associated with the current user from **File_1.txt**, and $A2[$i] should return the value from **File_2.txt**.

Above compares the associated values for user **$i** from both files..

```
                echo "$i has changed" > Output_File
```

Above adds the user **$i** to the **Output_File**

```
                if [ x$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE != x ]; then
                    USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE=",$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE"
                fi
                USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE="$i$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE"
```

Above creates a comma separated list of users who did not change.  Note there are no spaces in the list, or else the next check would need to be quoted.

```
        if [ x$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE != x ]; then
            echo "no change: $USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE"
        fi
```

Above reports the value of **$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE** but only if there is a value in **$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE**.  The way this is written, **$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE** cannot contain any spaces.  If it does need spaces, above could be rewritten as follows:

```
        if [ "$USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE" != "" ]; then
            echo "no change: $USERSWHODIDNOTCHANGE"
        fi
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Additional answer

If there's no need to know what parts of the files differ, you can use checksum of the file. There's many ways to do that, using `md5sum` or `sha256sum`. Basically , each of them outputs a string to which a file contents hash. If the two files are the same, their hash will be the same as well. This is often used when you download software, such as Ubuntu installation iso images. They're often used for verifying integrity of a downloaded content.

Consider script below, where you can give two files as arguments, and the file will tell you if they are the same or not.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Check if both files exist  
if ! [ -e "$1"  ];
then
    printf "%s doesn't exist\n" "$1"
    exit 2
elif ! [ -e "$2" ]
then
    printf "%s doesn't exist\n" "$2"
    exit 2
fi

# Get checksums of eithe file
file1_sha=$( sha256sum "$1" | awk '{print $1}')
file2_sha=$( sha256sum "$2" | awk '{print $1}')

# Compare the checksums
if [ "x$file1_sha" = "x$file2_sha" ]
then
    printf "Files %s and %s are the same\n" "$1" "$2"
    exit 0
else
    printf "Files %s and %s are different\n" "$1" "$2"
    exit 1
fi
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./compare_files.sh /etc/passwd ./passwd_copy.txt                                                                
Files /etc/passwd and ./passwd_copy.txt are the same
$ echo $?
0
$ ./compare_files.sh /etc/passwd /etc/default/grub                                                                
Files /etc/passwd and /etc/default/grub are different
$ echo $?
1
```

#### Older answer

In addition there is `comm` command, which compares two sorted files, and gives output in 3 colums : column 1 for items unique to file #1, column 2 for items unique to file #2, and column 3 for items present in both files.

To suppress either column you can use switches -1, -2 , and -3. Using -3 will show the lines that differ.

Bellow you can see the screenshot of the command in action.

[image]

There is just one requirement - the files must be sorted for them to be compared properly. `sort` command can be used for that purpose. Bellow is another screenshot , where files are sorted and then compared. Lines starting on the left bellong to File_1 only , lines starting on column 2 belong to File_2 only

[image]

Comment: @DavidFoerster it's kinda hard to be editing on mobile :) Done now, though

Answer (score 1):

Even if this question is about "command line", I propose another GUI tool:
kompare, from KDE. I find it so effective
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use an IDE like `CLion`, right click on the file you want to compare, you may see the message `compare with`.  Add the file you want to compare with. Also, as shortcut, select the file you want to compare and press `ctrl+D`, this option is very handy.