# File and folder comparison tool that compares only filenames?

Tags: files, duplicate-files

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12473/file-and-directory-comparison-tool) already, which has a lot of good answers, but as far as I can tell none of the programs listed compare **only** the filenames. What program can I use to compare two directories and list which files only exist in one or other directory?

I would strongly prefer a GUI, but I'm quite capable of using command line if I must.

**Additional Info**

I have a **lot** of files (in the range of 125,000+ per directory), so the tool MUST NOT compare the contents of the files, only the filenames, or it'll take forever.

Comment: see also on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217628/diff-to-output-only-the-file-names) and also [on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/166317/linux-compare-directory-structure-without-comparing-files)

Comment: @KasiyA The SO link: `diff` always checks inside files, even with the `-q` switch. The SU link: Yes, I found that and tried it as per my comment on my accepted answer :)

Comment: I tested them both of them are correct but in SU you need to change `d`to `f` ;)

Comment: @KasiyA Yup, that or remove the `type` switch altogether (which is what I did).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a simple method, install the `tree` command:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
tree folderA > folderA.txt
tree folderB > folderB.txt
```

Then use a GUI diff tool such as `meld` to compare both listings.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I'm currently running through another potential solution I found that may or may not work - if it doesn't, I'll try your method. I'll answer my own question if my current method works satisfactorily.

Comment: I tried [this method](http://superuser.com/a/166322). It worked, but produced a less-than-ideal output. Then I tried your method. A+ works perfectly! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [dupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/)

dupeGuru is a tool to find duplicate files on your computer. It can scan either filenames or contents. The filename scan features a fuzzy matching algorithm that can find duplicate filenames even when they are not exactly the same.<sup>[dupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/)</sup>

Comment: Can it list the opposite? That is, can it list files that are *not* the same? I don't want to know which files are the same, rather which are different.

Comment: I don't think that it will do that.  For that you may want to take a look at [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear that in mind, but I'd prefer not to have to write a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

`Gnome Commander` has a built-in feature of `Compare Directories` (shortcut Shift+F2).

The different files are marked after comparison (red in the screenshot).

See screenshot:
[image]